# circular reference memory leak in C++

Tags: c++

I am reading safe C++ and author mentioned about circular reference as below.

Consider two objects containing pointers to each other

```
class A;

class B { public: A* a; };

class A { public: B* b; };
```

This situation is known as a "circular reference". Pointers exist to A and to B, but if there are no ohter pointers to atleast one of these objects from somewhere else, there
is no way to reclaim the memory for either variable and therefore you create a memory leak. These two objects will live happily ever after and never be destroyed.

My question

1. Why there is memory leak? Why is it bad idea to delete memory in destructor of corresponding class?
2. On what basis author mentioned that two objects live ever after?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: This is kind of hard to answer, because it is not the fact that you have pointers going each way, but rather smart reference counted pointers, which your example is not.

Comment: You don't have two objects containing pointers to each other in this example.

Comment: The subject (which has nothing to do with your sample code) deals with  a garbage collecting algorithm that uses basic reference counting. If two objects reference each *other* and are unlinked from all outside references they are *unreachable*, but basic reference counting doesn't account for this. Therefore, they stay allocated (because they reference each other) and their memory is never reclaimed. This is producible using shared smart pointers when relying on them to clean up on destruction, but they never destruct because of the circle. Weak pointers are one way to manage this problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are some garbage collection algorithms sufficiently simple that they would fail to collect two unreachable objects that reference each other (basically, if the gc uses reference-counting only).

However, C++ doesn't guarantee to provide any garbage collection at all. And the code you have shown doesn't even use reference counting. So as far as what you show is concerned, the reason that objects are leaked (if any objects are leaked) is nothing to do with circular references, it's because you didn't free them.

It seems likely that the book you reference is speaking in the context of some additional information that you have chosen not to show in this question -- probably there's some reference-counting in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The concept in question is reachability.  Basically, starting
from a base set of pointers (active variables, etc.), can you
reach the object in question, directly or indirectly.  If not,
the object is unreachable.

A trivial example of an unreachable object is one to which there
is no pointer.  The circular reference example is another
example: there are pointers to both of the objects in question,
but the objects are still not reachable.

In most languages, if an object is unreachable, it will be
garbage collected, sooner or later.  In C++, you are required to
explicitly delete any dynamically allocated object before it
becomes unreachable; otherwise, you can never delete it (and
memory has leaked).  One frequent C++ technique for simulating
garbage collection is reference counted pointers; this technique
(unlike other garbage collection techniques) does not handle
circular references correctly, and will thus leak memory.

While C++ would benefit from garbage collection, it's important
to realize that this is *not* as much an issue in C++ as in most
other languages.  In C++, dynamically allocated objects usually
only correspond to objects which have defined lifetimes, and
which will be destructed explicitly in response to some external
events (or which will never be destructed, because once the
program has finished with them, the program has finished,
period—think of the parse tree in a compiler).  Because
C++ supports value semantics, most other objects are *not*
dynamically allocated, but are rather local variables, or data
members of a larger object, and have their lifetime
automatically managed.  Although C++ has a number of
“smart” pointers to automatically manage deleting
memory, if you find yourself drawn to using them extensively,
you're probably abusing dynamic allocation.

Comment: @ James. Thanks for detailed explanation but I have one question what do you mean by "there are pointers to both of the objects in question, but the objects are still not reachable." Can you please eloborate? Thanks

Comment: There is still a pointer which exists which points to A, and there is still a pointer which exists which points to B, but neither of these pointers is "reachable"; i.e. if you start from the base set of pointers, you can never get to either of these objects.